# Why are functions running before they are called?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am making a python script:

```
import tkinter

def print_the_nothing_thing():
    print("I told you, nothing means nothing. For further assistance, please see:")
    print("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3WNlWyFgLCg")
    print("Type the url into the browser.")

#setup the window
window = tkinter.Tk()
menu = tkinter.Menu(window)
window.configure(menu=menu)
view = tkinter.Menu(menu)
file = tkinter.Menu(menu)
menu.add_cascade(label="File", menu=file)
menu.add_cascade(label="View", menu=view)
#here is my problem
view.add_command(label="Nothing here!", command=print_the_nothing_thing())
file.add_command(label="Nothing here!", command=print_the_nothing_thing())
helpm.add_command(label="Help", command=helpy())
window.mainloop()
```

My problem is that when I define the function, it runs the function first. After closing it, the menu command does nothing.

Comment: What evidence do you have that this is happening?  And does it look like `print_the_nothing_thing` is being called twice, and then `helpy` is being called once?

Comment: What tutorial/information are you using for tkinter? I'm pretty sure that you haven't read the documentation correctly, and added parentheses where they shouldn't be.

Comment: @ScottHunter Yes, `print_the_nothing_thing` is 2 times and `helpy` is once.

Comment: Experimenting in a separate small file is an excellent practice.  Keep it up. Among other things, it lets you post a near minimal file that actually runs, making it easy to find the problem.  More beginners should do the same,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to remove `()` from those `add_command` lines, like

```
view.add_command(label="Nothing here!", command=print_the_nothing_thing)
file.add_command(label="Nothing here!", command=print_the_nothing_thing)
```

You are calling those functions there, and they return `None`. If you use just the name of the function, you get a function object.

Answer (score 2):

You're calling the function in `add_command`:

```
view.add_command(label="Nothing here!", command=print_the_nothing_thing())
file.add_command(label="Nothing here!", command=print_the_nothing_thing())
helpm.add_command(label="Help", command=helpy())
```

Instead, point `add_command` to the function name; don't execute it.
Thus:

```
view.add_command(label="Nothing here!", command=print_the_nothing_thing)
file.add_command(label="Nothing here!", command=print_the_nothing_thing)
helpm.add_command(label="Help", command=helpy)
```